# Run Playn HTML project in Remote

Tags: java, html, playn

I made my game running on html with mvn -Phtml integration-test

does anyone know how to test it online now? What kind of server do I need and how do I make it work on internet?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://developers.google.com/appengine/ very easily with playn. Theres some documentation here about how to do it: https://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted#Running_your_new_game_on_App_Engine

Answer (score 0):

Well, really what your asking is how you can make an HTML file with it's files into a public domain anyone can visit, right? Well, all you need to do is host it using an online web hosting service. Google "web hosting service" and you should be able to find one.